# hannesa2:paho.mqtt library run time error

Tags: android, mqtt

I'm using hannesa2:paho.mqtt library in my app.

```
implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
implementation 'com.github.hannesa2:paho.mqtt.android:4.2'
```

When I start run app I got this error. Then I also can't call mqtt method after compile library.

Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultLenientConfiguration$ArtifactResolveException: Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.